# which phone for the most of Android versions?

Tags: android, testing, versions

Im developing an Android app and I would like to test it on a real device so that I'd like to get a phone, on which a different version of Android can be installed, upgraded and downgraded.

Which phone can run most of Android versions? How should I choose it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Nexus series is a great choice for that. The newest version always come first for them, even for older devices like Nexus 5

Comment: I think you should stick to emulators. Most of the problems on different Android devices are due to different hardware, so trying different versions on the same phone isn't as useful as it sounds. Though I can say the nexus 5 is good for development.

Comment: @pkacprzak Thank you. How much can I downgrade it? Can I even go to the 2.x.x versions?

Comment: @Up I'll definitely work with them, still I'd like to have a real device..

Comment: For nexus devices there is usually no more than 4 or 5 major versions : https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Answer (score 1):

[This answer applies to official Google releases of the Android software, not to alternate distros like Cyanogen.]

There are very few devices that even support more than one or two versions of the Android system. Carriers and OEMs seem reluctant to upgrade devices at all, and when devices do receive major upgrades, they rarely get more than one.

Of course, Android is open source, so you can build whatever version you want, right? Not really. Although the base OS is open source, OEMs have no obligation to release the actual source used to build the kernel and userland for any particular device. With a closed-source device, upgrading is out of the question. The best you can hope for is a downgrade, if you can find the right binaries.

As one commenter noted, Nexus devices are in general a good choice. They are usually supported for at least three OS revisions, and can be upgraded and downgraded easily. With few exceptions, they run 100% open source software.

If you're willing to get your hands dirty, the device that supports the most versions is the [Panda](http://pandaboard.org/) board, which for many years was the standard test board for the Android Open Source Project. It was recently replaced by the [HiKey](http://www.96boards.org/products/ce/hikey/) board, which is more powerful and less expensive. If you don't mind building a device out of raw components, the combination of a HiKey and a Panda will cost less than a single Nexus device and likely remain valid for years to come.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go with the emulators but if you want a real device you should test on a Nexus device, but even nexus devices can't cover all the platforms
You can find most of the Android official versions [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#hikey20160226)

Also you can find custom ROMs for different phones [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/)

**Note** 
Even if you flash ROMs on some devices, you still might get into different issues on different platforms because Android is customized by each phone manufacturers. For example, the Android that runs on the Nexus devices is the official Google version, but is different than the one that runs on a Samsung, HTC, Sony, etc.